# Summing values over multiple, non-related tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I have three tables: users, sales and points.

Each user has multiple sales and multiple points.

Sales have a column "value" and points have a column "score", like so

```
users = | user_id | name |

sales = | sale_id | user_id | value |

points = | point_id | user_id | score |
```

Now I want to show a listing of all users with sums of their sales and points like so

```
user_id | sum(sales.value) | sum(points.value)
1       |   500            |    200
2       |   213            |    132
3  .  .  .
```

Is it possible to achieve in one query, without using subqueries?

Or what is the best, the simpliest approach? I'm trying to simplify this as much as possible because I have lots of information related to users that I have to show in this manner.

I tried using left joins but when I join two one-to-many tables in one query, the sum obviously becomes messed up because of the repeated rows. I tried grouping the data but I think I'm lost.

Comment: You need to use subqueries.  Why don't you want to use them?

Comment: Thanks, that's all I needed to know. It's not that I didn't want to, I was wondering if there's another approach that I might not be aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "right" approach in SQL is to summarize the tables before joining them:

```
select u.user_id, sumvalue, sumscore
from users u left outer join
     (select user_id, sum(value) as sumvalue
      from sales
      group by user_id
     ) s
     on u.user_id = s.user_id left outer join
     (select user_id, sum(score) as sumscore
      from points
      group by user_id
     ) p
     on u.user_id = p.user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the following data, this sql gives these results --

```
user_id user_name
1   Davolio
2   Fuller
3   Leverling
4   Peacock
5   Buchanan
6   Suyama
7   King
8   Callahan
9   Dodsworth

sale_id user_id sale_value
10248   5   $32.38
10249   6   $11.61
10250   4   $65.83
10251   3   $41.34
10252   1   $51.30
10253   3   $58.17
10254   5   $22.98
10255   9   $148.33
10256   3   $13.97
10257   4   $81.91

point_id    user_id score
10319   7   64
10320   5   35
10321   3   3
10322   7   0 
10323   4   5
10324   9   214
10325   1   65
10326   4   78
10327   2   63
10333   5   1
10334   8   9

SELECT users.user_id,
       users.user_name,
       (SELECT SUM(sale_value)  FROM   sales
       WHERE  sales.user_id = users.user_id)  AS SalesValue,
       (SELECT SUM(score)       FROM   points
      WHERE  points.user_id = users.user_id) AS ScoreValue
FROM   users; 

user_id  user_name  SalesValue  ScoreValue
1   Davolio           $51.30    65
2   Fuller                     63
3   Leverling         $113.48   3
4   Peacock           $147.74   83
5   Buchanan          $55.36    36
6   Suyama            $11.61    
7   King                        64
8   Callahan                   9
9   Dodsworth        $148.33    214
```